# Were the races in the original Star Trek meant to represent different real countries?

Tags: star-trek

I once heard that e.g. the Klingons were meant to represent the Russians, and so on for other races; at least in Star Trek: the original series.

Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: I always thought that cardassians were like the nazis.The style and appereance is like them. As in real life some were good to their slaves while most were not. But when I look at them something reminds me of the nazis.

Comment: @user53337 Strangely enough, the Nazi's of the Third Reich, for all their attrocities, did not engage in chattel slavery. Contrast with American or Brazilian enslavers who bought and sold, forcibly mated (i.e. raped) slaves together, and sold the offspring for profit.

Comment: Nazis. I think Chekov was supposed to represent the Russians.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes and no.

The Original Series (TOS) has a mix of both.  Like most sci-fi, it wasn't written about the future, it was written about the (then) present day.

For many of the stories, such as 'The Cage', 'The Tholian Web', and 'The Man Trap', the aliens were not meant to represent any single person or race.  They were hardly characters, being defined mainly by the requirements of the plot.  They were obstacles to be overcome or avoided.

The Klingons, however, were a race locked in a cold war with the Federation, and it was meant to exemplify the feelings of the time.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon#Conception) says this:

> The Klingons took on the role of the Soviet Union in opposition to the
>   United States' future counterpart, the United Federation of Planets.

It is referenced as follows:

> Westmore, Michael; Alan Sims, Bradley M. Look, William J. Birnes
>   (2000). Star Trek: Aliens and Artifacts. Star Trek. pp. 208. ISBN
>   0671042998.

Thus we can see that it is true in some cases, and not true for many others.  In other cases, such as the Romulans, it is not so clear-cut.

Comment: Of course, Klingons had money and Federation were plinco commie bastards... so the analogy was somewhat... ironic :)

Comment: @dvk wrong. See Trouble with Tribbles - feds had currency.

Comment: @aramis - the issue of Star Trek monetary policy and economy was kicked to death in other questions :)

Comment: @dvk and you still got it wrong because of conflation of TNG and TOS/TAS

Comment: @aramis - TOS had a jumble of money/moneyless society! I'm just the messenger! :)))

Comment: Arguably in TNG, the Romulans have parallels with the Russians at that point in real-world history - powerful and somewhat mysterious, emerging from years of isolation.

Comment: I always took Klingons as a very clear and obvious "space viking"

Answer (score 11):

Less real races, more various cultures and, even more specifically, various pieces of the human psyche.

TOS's basic premise, in Roddenberry's mind, was that humans had transcended the primary weakness of human consciousness that held them back from realizing their full potential; greed, which for millenia has caused us to compete with each other for wealth and power  instead of cooperating toward a common goal. Now, given that we're no longer fighting each other, there has to be some source of conflict to make a TV series interesting.

Enter the other races, each one of them a powerful, often one-note statement on a human weakness.

The Klingons were patterned on a mix of various warrior cultures, primarily Asian (hence Kor's somewhat Chinese facial hair) but with a scattering of Norse mythology thrown in. In the original series, and even in the TOS-era movies, they didn't go much into Klingon society other than that they lusted for glory in combat and conquest of their enemies, and saw the Federation as both a serious threat to their way of life, and the ultimate test of their race's superiority. The Next Generation, with Worf as a main character, forced the writers to flesh out some of the missing pieces, primarily the introduction of the hybrid Norse/Eastern honor code. This was further developed in DS9 as the Klingon Empire continues the on-again, off-again alliance with the Federation against the Cardassians and eventually the Dominion.

The Vulcans, pretty much the complete opposite. Closer to humans, but humans value our emotions while Vulcans seek to suppress them in favor of cold, calculating logic. I don't know if it's always been the canon story that the Vulcans were our official first contact with an extraterrestrial race, or if that was added in bits and pieces, but the currently-accepted canon is that a Vulcan survey ship just happened to be in the area of the Sol system and picked up the warp signature of Dr. Cochrane's historic first manned FTL spaceflight. Their open appearance to humans and subsequent guidance led the humans to "put away childish things", and this influence is obvious in the new Human society. The Vulcans are often held up as where the Humans should be in another thousand years or so, with or without their emotions.

The Romulans were originally patterned directly after their namesake, the Romans. Romulan society functioned on the sole principle that there was always another world to conquer, occupy, and exploit for its own gain, much like the Romans sought to bring the entire known world, and its wealth, under the control of Caesar. Canon sources from TOS onward state that the Romulans are closely biologically related to the Vulcans; one or the other faction rejected their sister race's ideals and broke away, thousands of years before the events of any Star Trek series. Canon sources are unclear about whether the Romulans or Klingons had the cloaking technology first, but the TOS canon sets the Romulans up as scavengers of sorts, stealing or otherwise acquiring technology from the races they encounter. The Romulan Bird of Prey seen in TOS is strikingly similar to Federation saucer-and-nacelle designs, which in-script is made note of and speculated on; the "native" Romulan D'deridex heavy cruiser of the TNG era, by contrast, looks vaguely similar to the wings-and-nose Klingon ship designs.

Most other races in TOS were relative one-offs, and so they offered the opportunity for a one-note social commentary; in one TOS episode that comes to mind, "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield", the Enterprise comes across two members of a race, with one half of their face and body white and the other black, and which half was which was of central importance to the culture's social standing. The two, it's revealed, are the last survivors of their planet after a global war erupted during their absence chasing each other through space, apparently the result of the same racial conflict. Despite the cataclysmic results of their hatred staring them in the face, they still cannot put aside their differences, and Kirk has to beam them to the surface of their dead planet to save his ship from their fighting.

These basic patterns continue through the TNG era, with a few more recurring races and a few new ones, such as the Ferengi (the ultimate statement of capitalism and sexism in the Star Trek canon), the Cardassians (basically the "new Romulans" after the Romulans were backed away from their conquer-everything mentality to give TNG some deeper story material), the Dominion races (one of many examples of a super-race that regards all others as inferior), and the Borg (generally a statement on the loss of individuality and the idea of sentient beings thinking like computers). In Voyager, really only the names change; the Kazon are Delta-quadrant Klingons with much the same values and a little less civility, the Vidiians are a relatively novel concept that ends up being a hybrid of Borg and Romulan, and Species 8472 is yet another super-race, though this time way beyond the Dominion's level (or pretty much anything in the known galaxy).

Comment: Note that in "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield" Kirk didn't beam them down to the planet, rather Lokai beamed himself down as a tactical escape from Bele (who was chasing him at the time), and then Bele beamed himself down to the planet to continue the fight.

Answer (score 5):

The Klingons and Romulans serving as proxies for the Soviets and Communist Chinese in TOS stories when necessary for real world anecdotes  is pretty common knowledge. As is the sort of Mongol/Hun influence on the Klingons and Roman influence on the Romulans regarding their actual culture.

When you get to TNG this continues as in real life the Soviet Union was collapsing and becoming more of an uneasy ally at the time while the Chinese, and to an extent the North Koreans and Iranians, were the last real world political rivals to the the US/NATO. I do think the isolation of N. Korea and Iran influenced the portrayal of the Romulans in TNG.

Of races introduced in TNG the Ferengi serving as the "evils of capitalism" since the Klingons/Soviets were no longer a threat is pretty common knowledge. The Borg are also well known to be the dark side of technology mixed with cults and going off of cults some might argue orthodox communism or radical Islam in their "convert or die" ideologies but I think that's more of reality imitating art as Al Qaeda and ISIS were not really known at the time of the Borg's creation.

I do think the Cardassians and Bajorans are interesting and get overlooked a lot. Many compare the Cardassians to the Nazis and I think there's some truth there but again looking at the world in the early 90s when they were created and they are even more like South American and Iberian military dictatorships of the 70s and 80s; most clearly Argentina or Chile. The federation works with the Cardassians despite their despicable human rights record to "preserve peace" much as the US backed Pinochet and Videla in the context of the Cold War. Those regimes were notorious for the types of torture and "disappearances" we see the Cardassians engage in. We are told that Cardassia was peaceful but due to economic problems turned to a right wing military dictatorship- this is typical of the rise fascist type regimes in general and is usually a go to from defenders of Franco and Pinochet to this day: that they saved the economy and "made ____ great again". Finally our introduction to the Cardassians in the late 80s cast them as a regional power that fought a costly border war over territory but is not truly an existential threat to the Federation as their technology and military aren't at the level of the Federation. This always sounded like the Falkland's War to me.

Finally the Bajorans are a clever if not controversial mix of Israeli and Palestinian with a touch of Irish Republican. This of course gives the Cardassians a role in which they serve as the British and/or Israelis.

Answer (score 4):

I have pondered this question myself over the years.  I strongly believe there are real-world counterparts in the Star Trek galaxy.  My theories on the matter, based on the Cold War analogy:

Federation = NATO.  Group of freedom loving planets (countries) with the Earth (USA) as the superpower.

Klingons = Russians/Soviets.  Dictatorship with emphasis on military spending, spartan quality of life.  Guttural language.

Vulcans = Japanese.  Logical, emotionally reserved, black hair, asiatic complexion -- pointy ears instead of slanted eyes.  Previously warlike and violent, but recently found their role as peace-loving non-combatants with a defense force but never or rarely involved in any galactic battles.

Romulans = Chinese and/or North Koreans. Rarely seen, no real diplomatic ties.  Referred to as distant "cousins" to the Vulcans.  Neutral zone = Korean DMZ.

I read before that Roddenberry denied any real-world connection, but of course he'd have had to back then to avoid "racial profiling" or something.  Kind of like how MASH was actually a protest of the Vietnam war but set in the Korean War to avoid too much suspicion and thus a conservative backlash.  Or being flat out banned altogether by the motion picture system of the day.

Comment: fwiw - M.A.S.H. was originally a book, written by a real M.A.S.H doctor who served in the Korean War. If it was was antiwar, it was antiwar in a general way, not targeted as a veiled statement about Vietnam. The Vietnam connection was co-opted by the producers of the film and TV series and simply seen as speaking about Vietnam because that was the current / most recent conflict